# T-SQL Delete first xml row

Tags: xml, t-sql, sql-server-2012, row

I have the following XML:

```
<row>
  <el>Field1</el>
  <el>Field2</el>
  <el>Field3</el>
  <el>Field4</el>
  <el>Field5</el>
  <el>Field6</el>
</row>
<row>
  <el>R1C1</el>
  <el>R1C2</el>
  <el>R1C3</el>
  <el>R1C4</el>
  <el>R1C5</el>
  <el>R1C6</el>
</row>
<row>
  <el>R2C1</el>
  <el>R2C2</el>
  <el>R2C3</el>
  <el>R2C4</el>
  <el>R2C5</el>
  <el>R2C6</el>
</row>
<row>
```

and I want to delete the first row? I need to do this in order to insert in table onlt the second and third rows of the given XML structure. This is what I am doing:

```
SET @TSVDataXML = '<row>' + REPLACE( ( '<el><![CDATA[' + REPLACE(@CommentText, CHAR(9), ']]></el><el><![CDATA[') + ']]></el>' ), CHAR(13), ']]></el></row><row><el><![CDATA[' ) + '</row>'
SELECT @TSVDataXML
INSERT INTO @ResultTable(Field1,Field2,Field3,Field4,Field5,Field6)
SELECT tbl.col.value('el[1]','NVARCHAR(20)')
      ,tbl.col.value('el[2]','NVARCHAR(20)')
      ,tbl.col.value('el[3]','NVARCHAR(20)')
      ,tbl.col.value('el[4]','NVARCHAR(20)')
      ,tbl.col.value('el[5]','NVARCHAR(20)')
      ,tbl.col.value('el[6]','NVARCHAR(20)')
FROM @TSVDataXML.nodes('//row') AS tbl(col)
```

So, alternative solution to my problem will be to add a where clause where the first row is not inserted. Unfortunately, I am not very good in XML stuff.

Any advice, answer or article will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will delete the first row in the XML.

```
set @TSVDataXML.modify('delete row[1]')
```

Have a look at [delete (XML DML)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190254.aspx)

Or you could exclude the first row in the nodes XPath expression using [position()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191225.aspx).

```
from @TSVDataXML.nodes('//row[position() > 1]') as tbl(col)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answers and especially for the references.